# Why doesn't the line connect points from left to right?

Tags: stata

What's the problem here?

I used two-way `line var1 var2, width(thick)`.

where `var2` is the fitted polynomial value

The image is attached below

[image]

Answer (score 3):

That syntax would not produce that graph. Note that `two-way` would not work: `twoway` would. Something more like

```
scatter log_inc age || line var2 age, sort
```

is needed here. What you are missing is the `sort` option. By default `graph` joins points in their order in the dataset, which is not what you want here.

This is prominently documented: see [the help on `line`](http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?line)